# How to adjust the widths of "S"-type columns in a table?

Tags: tables, siunitx

This problem is based on [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291960/156170) for printing confidence intervals in a table.
The issue arises when the values within the confidence intervals consists
of five or more digits. What happens is that the values overflow the column
width (see image) and the first interval value is printed outside of the brackets.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{
    c
    S[table-format = 1.1]
    >{{[}} % Add square bracket before column
    S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-pre={[}]
    @{,\,} % Add comma and thin-space between the columns
    S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post={]}]
    <{{]}} % Add square bracket after column
  }
    A      & {B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CI} \cr
    Values & 2.3 &  9123.23 &  4567.23 \cr  % Too many digits to fit
    Values & 2.3 & -23.42 & -12.43 \cr
    Values & 2.3 &  4.12 &  7.33 \cr   % The last two rows fits nicely
    Values & 2.3 & -1.03 & -9.11 \cr
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: ci column overflow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must adjust the `table-format=` options. A setting of `1.1` ("one digit before the decimal marker, one digit after") is appropriate for the first data column. For the second and third data columns, a setting of `-1.2` is wholly inappropriate, though, as the columns contain numbers with four digits before and two digits after the decimal marker. Change the setting to `4.2` and you'll be back in business.