# Grouping two columns into a confidence interval

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

The code below is adapted from the excellent work [in another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291786/how-to-print-tabular-confidence-intervals-as-x-y-with-siunitx). However, I'm trying to adapt it to my specific use-case and am having two issues:

- I'd rather use parentheses instead of brackets. In other words, I'd like it to appear as `0.4 (-1.8, 2.5)` instead of `0.4 [-1.8, 2.5]`. However, I get `Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '(-1.791145'.` when I substitute `>{{(}}` for `>{{[}}`.
- The `>`, `@` and `<` directives also operate on the header columns, leaving a strange `[ , ]` above the `Mean (95% CI)` cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{\em}l
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1]
    >{{[}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-pre={[}] 
    @{,\,}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-post={]}]
    <{{]}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
}

\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{dB re. 40/s conv.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
{} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
{{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean (95\% CI)}&{$<\pm 2.5dB$}&{$<\pm 5dB$} \\
\midrule
oranges  &          0.410188 & -1.791145 &  2.505052 &     0.967500 &   0.999875 \\
bananas   &          0.006144 & -2.185644 &  2.184911 &     0.973375 &   0.999875 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of code output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your example document compilable, by adding the missing `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`s (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: The number of braces associated with the `S` specifier are creating the problem---https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493771/197451

Comment: Thank you. That solved my first question.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem was already solved in comments (with this link: [siunitx error: Invalid numerical input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493765/siunitx-error-invalid-numerical-input/493771#493771)).

For the second problem, you can use a `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{\itshape}l
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1]
    >{{[~}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-pre={[~}] 
    @{,\,}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-post={~]}]
    <{{~]}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
}

\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{dB re. 40/s conv.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
{} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
{{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean (95\% CI)}&{$<\pm 2.5dB$}&{$<\pm 5dB$} \\
\midrule
oranges  &          0.410188 & -1.791145 &  2.505052 &     0.967500 &   0.999875 \\
bananas   &          0.006144 & -2.185644 &  2.184911 &     0.973375 &   0.999875 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]